# WYSIWYG for math formulas?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting, editor

Is there any website or tool that allows you to create math formulas visually which can then be pasted on this website?

I'm looking for something like the equation editor in Microsoft Word or Google Docs.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)?

Comment: @J.M.: nope, that's a pretty useful website. Still not entirely WYSIWYG, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: I'm working on a project that does exactly this. It's not ready yet but I'll report back when it is. If you want a preview, check out http://hristo.oskov.com/Kamma (I recommend using Chrome)

Comment: Maybe [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editors) at Wikipedia might be useful for you.

Comment: We need a [WYSIHYD editor](http://www.xkcd.com/1341/) for copy-pasted homework.

Comment: Same question on TeX.SE → https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57068/250119

Answer (score 6):

- **LyX** is almost a WYSIWYG editor to generate document parsed by TeX engine. You can create a math environment with Ctrl+M, type the formula with help of a GUI, and then copy the whole environment. This place the TeX code of the formula into the clipboard.
- **MathType** also support copy-as-TeX when you have enabled it.
- **Mathematica** has the `TeXForm[]` function to convert its expression into TeX code, *but* it will have nonstandard commands.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all my questions, answers and comments here have been created in version 4.10 of [MacKichan Software](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html%20s%20Scientific%20WorkPlace)'s [Scientific WorkPlace (SWP)](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/swp.html~mainFrame). The latest version is 5.5.

Here is an example

[image]

which generates the following code

\frac{1}{4}<\left( x-\frac{5}{2}\right) ^{2}<\frac{9}{4}\Leftrightarrow 
\frac{1}{2}<\left\vert x-\frac{5}{2}\right\vert <\frac{3}{2}

enclosed in $$

$$\frac{1}{4}<\left( x-\frac{5}{2}\right) ^{2}<\frac{9}{4}\Leftrightarrow 
\frac{1}{2}<\left\vert x-\frac{5}{2}\right\vert <\frac{3}{2}$$

and a quote from the site:

> You can create, edit, and typeset mathematical and scientific text
>   more easily than ever before. The software is based on an easy-to-use
>   word processor that completely integrates writing mathematics and text
>   in the same environment. With the built-in computer algebra system,
>   you can perform computations right on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

These are some free version I found on the web that works well enough.

I found another one here
http://camdenre.github.io/src/app/html/EquationEditor

I found an okay one here http://visualmatheditor.equatheque.net/

This one is free but I haven't tried that
http://visualmatheditor.equatheque.net/site/download.html

I was hoping that I can find an even better one where we can work on the actual equation. Something like Microsoft Equation editor but with text version that we can debug too.

I think the note should be useful for many I just don't know a more appropriate place to put it.

I will add more list.

Don't just type text and see some result like savage

[image]

Note: I am a programmer. So if I like GUI rather than writing some code to produce something you should be.