# Corresponding highlight when editing MathJax

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, editing, markdown-preview

When editing a complex formula, it is easy to get lost in a sea of MathJax code. The suggested feature is, when editing posts with MathJax:

(1) When a portion of a MathJax code is selected in the edit box, the corresponding portion of its result in the preview is highlighted.

(2) If none of a MathJax code is selected in the edit box, but the cursor in the edit box is inside a MathJax code, then one character at the corresponding position of the MathJax result in the preview is highlighted.

(3) When a portion of a MathJax result is selected in the preview, the corresponding portion of its code is highlighted in the edit box.

(4) When a MathJax result is clicked in the preview, the cursor in the edit box is set to the corresponding code of the clicked position in the result.

Comment: There's an easy solution: get a job as a typesetter for a journal. After that you'll never get lost in $\rm\LaTeX$ code ever again. At least not when it's on the scale of a MathJax inline code on a website like this. And it will also generate revenue for you on the side, so... win-win!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed I get lost in physics expression, but I think MathJax belongs to math site.

Comment: (1) I don't think that's a great feature request. (2) I wonder what you'd do if we were using KaTeX instead of MathJax...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Never heard of KaTex before. Alghouth you don't think its great, but I need this feature a lot and I believe a lot of others do, especially new users.

Comment: It's your prerogative to want a feature request. I am recording my opinion about it. The KaTeX remark was aimed at the "MathJax request should be on the math website" comment, which doesn't make sense to me, as a whole. (It's actually *not* a MathJax request, it's a StackExchange feature request, so by the same logic, it should perhaps go on [meta.se] instead.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila You said "not when it's on the scale of a MathJax inline code on a website like this" Then I realized maybe on math site the code is commonly shorter which make you not easy to get lost. But I find this need when I was editing physics expression on physics site. But the reason I asked it here is I think MathJax questions should be asked on math meta.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Now I'm confused, base on your logic, where should I post this question?

Comment: Yes, so let me reiterate, it's called **Math**Jax because it's meant to display mathematical formulas. It's not *directly* related to the mathematics website on SE. Moreover, you are not making *any* feature request about *MathJax*, but rather about the underlying SE software (which can go on any meta website, really), so by your logic that "MathJax should be discussed on math", "SE features should be discussed on meta.SE".

Comment: @AsafKaragila And MathJax in mainly used in math and physics site, I don't think it is quite fit for meta.se

Comment: Really? Just these two? Tell that to all the others mentioned on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax

Comment: Do you realise how demanding your first three requests are? For (4) you can use Overleaf.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No, never programmed with js

Comment: @AsafKaragila Did I make any mistake here? Since your tone made me feel so. Is it because my request is too demanding?

Comment: Is it really true that mathjax code on math.SE is commonly shorter? I'd be surprised :)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Can anyone tell me what exactly did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn’t do anything *wrong*, I think Asaf’s replies are to be taken as more playful than antagonistic, you can make the request here (but your reasoning to choose math.se’s meta is suspect), I don’t really want it, and I doubt it would be implemented. Keep in mind downvotes on meta indicate disagreement, not that u did something bad

Comment: @CalvinKhor First I considered meta, but  thought it will be highly possible to be closed for off topic there, and I only recently know that bad question can finally lead to question ban, not just downvote then close then delete. Why not physics? My MathJax experience begain here with the tutorial and quick reference and all my questions about it are here. I even edit the tutorial this morning.

Comment: This is a different feature request, but it is also intended to avoid getting lost when editing: [Ask Question app should have side-by-side view option](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25179) and [Feature request - but it woudn't be a feature, it'd be a blessing - editing panel and preview side-by-side - fighting lag on large answers!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10505)

Comment: If you need to make your editing process easier, you could also have a look the suggestion given here: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735) (and in [other linked posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4735))

Comment: @CalvinKhor That's pure antagonistic for me. I even want to finally leave - but who cares? High reputaion users keep the site run and that's the core asset of the site, and new users come and go. Anyway thanks for your kindness, that may even keep someone stay sometimes (possiblly not for me this time).

Comment: Maybe if you get lost when editing MathJax, it might be worth considering some WYSIWYG tool. I know about CodeCogs, but you might get better advice from people who use such tools regularly. Related posts: [WYSIWYG for math formulas?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1127), [MathJax WYSIWYG Editor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12967), [Latex editor suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5053).

Comment: @jw_ I suspect that due to the above mentioned interpretation of downvotes in SE's meta sites, you shouldn't worry about the question ban. (your question also has no close votes at the moment)

Comment: "When editing a complex formula, it is easy to get lost in a sea of MathJax code." - *partial solution* -  Often the editor will feel compelled to have the raw mathJax line breaks coordinate with the line breaks that appear when the mathJax is rendered.  Organizationally, that seems appropriate.  However, personally, when I am editing a complicated expression, I will forgo organizational concerns and use many more line breaks in the raw mathJax code.  This helps me avoid (or find and fix) syntax errors.